# Create JsonObject from @ResponseBody without using gson library

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-json

`@ResponseBody` returns

`[{"id":1010,"name":"projectname2"}]` type json string

But I need a following json string

`[{"id":1010,"name":"projectname2","age":"21"}]`

so how can I concat age attrribute to default genarated json string ?

Im using java spring-mvc framework with spring-json jar

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/projectsByEmployeeId/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<Project> getProjectsByEmployeeId(
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    String filter = request.getParameter("filter");
    FilterAttributes[] filterAttributes = null;
    try {
        filterAttributes = new ObjectMapper().readValue(filter,
                FilterAttributes[].class);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error("Filtering parameter JSON string passing failed",
                exception);
    }

    if ((filterAttributes != null)
            && (!filterAttributes[0].getStringValue().isEmpty())) {
        return utilityService.getProjectsByEmployeeId(44L);//this is an example id
    } else {
        return utilityService.getProjects();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for including the language that you are using - i'll see if i can get an answer soon **edit**: are you using Gson, or regular JSONObject's ?

Comment: How are you generating that JSON (the method code)? Can you paste it?

Comment: yes im using regular JSONObject in java

Comment: but you said without using any library?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this (you say that you are using JSONObject's now, and JSONObjects are NOT a default library)

Take the string,

```
[{"id":1010,"name":"projectname2"}]
```

And convert it to a JSONObject.

Once converted, you can use [JSONObject.append()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#append%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to append the key "age" with value "21" to it.

Comment: I have updated my code. I need to add new attribute before return it. how can I add it ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is pure string manipulation -

```
String json = "[{\"id\":1010,\"name\":\"projectname2\"}]";
json = json.substring(0, json.length() - 2); //strip the }]

String newJSON = json.concat(",\"age\": 21}]"); // add in the new key and end

System.out.println(newJSON); // [{"id":1010,"name":"projectname2","age": 21}]
```